# promise chaining reject

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am coding this chained promises.

First, when a button is clicked, it checks if a file url exists:

If not, it rejects, and then the response status is shown in an alert.

If yes, then it updates the DB via a webapi, then update the react state.

The problem I faced is, even I rejected in validateResponse function, it still run the next then.

I think it should go to the catch directly.

Besides, the below code to call webapi seems not good,  a promise inside a then, etc. also the whole code seems unclear? is it a better way to do so?

```
onClick: (event, row) => {


function validateResponse(response) {
  if (!response.ok) { // assume it is the reject case.
    console.log("file not ready");
    return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
  } else {
    window.open(response.url, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=500,width=600,scrollbars=no,status=yes')
    return response;
  }

}


fetch(row.fileurl, {
  method: 'HEAD'
})
.then(validateResponse)

.then(console.log("== this line not printed, due to rejected."))

.then(row.linked = 1)

.then( 
    fetch(this.server_url+'/file/linked', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(row),  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("== it should be rejected!, why printed this line2")
        if (res.status==200) {
          this.setState({ row });
        } else {
          row.checked = 0;
          throw Error(res.status);
        }

  })                            

)
.catch(function (error) {
    alert("Sorry, the file is not avaliable yet")
});


}
```

One more question:

```
.then(() => row.linked = 1)
.then(() => fetch(this.server_url+'/file/linked', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(row),  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, })
```

how to combine this into one?

```
.then(() => row.linked = 1 && fetch(this.server_url+'/file/linked', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(row),  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, })
```

is it a better/correct way to do so?

Comment: `.then` takes functions as parameters, but you put instructions in them. `.then(() => console.log(/*...*/))`, etc.

Comment: You can end up with a better optimisation after rolling the `validateResponse()` code into the promise chain.

Comment: You don't need an additional `.then()` after a wholly synchronous operation. You have two asynchronous operations, `fetch(row.fileurl, ...)` and `fetch(this.server_url + '/file/linked', ...)`, therefore everything will simplify to two thens and a catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the `Promise.reject` should make it work.

Issue is that when you don't specify a return value in a `.then` it will resolve the promise with an undefined value by default.

In your case, you should change your `validateResponse` so it returns the rejected promise:

`return Promise.reject(response.statusText);`

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value) for more info.

=================

Edit: Try with this code

```
onClick: (event, row) => {
  function validateResponse(response) {
    if (!response.ok) { // assume it is the reject case.
      console.log("file not ready");
      return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
    } else {
      window.open(response.url, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=500,width=600,scrollbars=no,status=yes')
      return response;
    }
  }

  fetch(row.fileurl, {
    method: 'HEAD'
  })
  .then(validateResponse)
  .then(() => console.log("== this line not printed, due to rejected."))
  .then(() => row.linked = 1)
  .then(() => fetch(this.server_url+'/file/linked', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(row),  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("== it should be rejected!, why printed this line2")
      if (res.status==200) {
        this.setState({ row });
      } else {
        row.checked = 0;
        throw Error(res.status);
      }
    })
  )
  .catch(function (error) {
      alert("Sorry, the file is not avaliable yet")
  });
}
```

========================

Edit2: `.then` accepts a function as callback. This means you can put it in one big function if you want:

```
onClick: (event, row) => {
  function validateResponse(response) {
    if (!response.ok) { // assume it is the reject case.
      console.log("file not ready");
      return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
    } else {
      window.open(response.url, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=500,width=600,scrollbars=no,status=yes')
      return response;
    }
  }

  fetch(row.fileurl, {
    method: 'HEAD'
  })
  .then(validateResponse)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("== this line not printed, due to rejected.");
    row.linked = 1;
    return fetch(this.server_url+'/file/linked', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(row),  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("== it should be rejected!, why printed this line2")
        if (res.status==200) {
          this.setState({ row });
        } else {
          row.checked = 0;
          throw Error(res.status);
        }
      })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      alert("Sorry, the file is not avaliable yet")
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried to add return, but it still goes to  this line: console.log("== it should be rejected!, why printed this line2")

Comment: @manhon you're not passing a callback to that last `.then()`, you're invoking `fetch()` there before the promise chain is even created. Same goes for your `console.log("== this line not printed, due to rejected.")` and your `row.linked = 1`...

Comment: can you reply with a fixed code, I tried for hour on many trial and error and still could not understand it..><

Comment: thanks so much, it works! can i ask one more question? I just added the question to the first post.

Comment: @Fleezey thank you so much! I fixed my poor understanding on promise now. many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling your second fetch in a callback and that is causing the fetch to fire **immediately**.

```
function someFunc() {
    // You are invoking the second fetch immediately
    fetch("example.com")
        .then(validate)
        .then(fetch("somewhere.com"))

    // You need to invoke it as a callback
    fetch("example.com")
        .then(validate)
        .then(() => fetch("somewhere.com"))

    // Or with non-arrow
    fetch("example.com")
        .then(validate)
        .then(function() {
            return fetch("somewhere.com");
        });
}
```